# change image source on click

Tags: c#, wpf

I've made a custom image for a checkbox and want it to switch between the checked and the unchecked version every time the image is clicked. My sourcecode:

**XAML**

```
<CheckBox Name="checkBox1" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1">
    <Image Name="image1" Margin="-14,0,0,0" Source="checkbox0.png" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown" Stretch="Uniform"/>
</CheckBox>
```

**C#**

```
private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
     {
         if (checkBox1checked)
         {
             image1.BeginInit();
             image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/checkbox0.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
             image1.EndInit();
             checkBox1checked = false;
         }

         if (!checkBox1checked)
         {
             image1.BeginInit();
             image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/checkbox1.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
             image1.EndInit();
             checkBox1checked = true;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Does it not work? Are you getting errors? What you have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Uncheck and Check event of the checkbox, and set the image source in there

```
<CheckBox Name="checkBox1" Padding="0" Unchecked="chkbox_Unchecked" Checked="chkbox_Checked BorderThickness="0" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1">
   <Image Name="image1" Margin="-14,0,0,0" Source="checkbox0.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
</CheckBox>




        private void chkbox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetImage("/checkbox0.png");
        }

        private void chkbox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             SetImage("/checkbox1.png");
        }

    private void SetImage(string path)
    {
        image1.BeginInit();
                image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                image1.EndInit();

    }
```

Comment: Unchecked="chkbox_Unchecked" Checked="chkbox_Checked"

Comment: made a tiny mistake in the code, one should be chkbox_UnChecked

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a logic error in your code behind, the second if statement will execute right after the first if since you changed the value of checkbox.

Also you defined image inside checkbox, this somehow reset the checkbox's value each time you initialize image, consider move image outside of checkbox or just use a public flag

```
<CheckBox Name="checkBox1" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1">
</CheckBox>
<Image Name="image1" Margin="-14,0,0,0" Source="checkbox0.png" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

change your code behind

```
private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            if (checkBox1checked)
            {
                image1.BeginInit();
                image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/checkbox0.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                image1.EndInit();
                checkBox1checked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                image1.BeginInit();
                image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/checkbox1.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                image1.EndInit();
                checkBox1checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Better try:

```
    private void chkbox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         SetImage("/checkbox1.png");
    }

        private void chkbox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         SetImage("/checkbox1.png");
    }
```